# how to release char**

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

how to release char** in jni?
I don't find any env function to release pstr below

```
Java_com_example_test(
JNIEnv* env,jobject,jobjectArray content){
 jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(content);
 char **pstr = (char**)malloc(len* sizeof(char*));
 jstring jstr;
 for (int i=0; i<len;i++){
     jstr = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(content,i);
     pstr[i]=(char*) env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr,0);
 }
 env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);
 // todo release pstr
```

Comment: `free(pstr);`?  Do you have to free the strings obtained from `GetStringUTFChars`?

Answer (score 1):

```
free(pstr);
pstr = NULL;
```

will free memory allocated with malloc, but before that you need to release memory allocated by VM to prevent memory leak.
From [Java SE doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

```
 const char * GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string,
jboolean *isCopy);
```

Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding. 
This array is valid until it is released by ReleaseStringUTFChars().